# simple client sever program in c++ not working

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, gcc

I am trying to create a simple client server program in c++ .The server and client execute until termination but The data doesn't transfer from server to client.
My server code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {



    int sid=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0); 

    int  clilen;

    int clisocket;

    char buffer[256];

    int portnumber=atoi("8888");

    struct sockaddr_in serverinfo,cliinfo;
    memset(&serverinfo, '0', sizeof(serverinfo));
    memset(&cliinfo, '0', sizeof(cliinfo));

    serverinfo.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serverinfo.sin_port=htons(portnumber);
    serverinfo.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;


    bind(sid,(struct sockaddr *)&serverinfo,sizeof(serverinfo));

    listen(sid,1000);


    clilen=sizeof(clilen);


    clisocket=accept(sid,(struct sockaddr*)&cliinfo,(socklen_t*)clilen);

    bzero(buffer,256);


    printf("before server \n");
    write(clisocket,"hello",5);
    printf("after server \n");


    close(clisocket);

    close(sid);

    return 0;
}
```

and my client code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char buffer[256];
    bzero(buffer,256);

    int cid=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    int port=atoi("8888");

    struct sockaddr_in serverinfo;

    memset(&serverinfo, '0', sizeof(serverinfo));

    struct hostent* host;

    memset(&host, '0', sizeof(host));

    host=gethostbyname("localhost");

    serverinfo.sin_family=host->h_addrtype;
    memcpy((char *) &serverinfo.sin_addr.s_addr, host->h_addr_list[0], host->h_length);
    serverinfo.sin_port=htons(port);


    int statusconnect=connect(cid,(sockaddr*)&serverinfo,sizeof(serverinfo));


    printf("before read client \n");
    read(cid,buffer,255);
    printf("after client read");
    printf(buffer); //not print this!!!

    printf(buffer);
    close(cid);

    return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate for any bit of help.

Comment: Unless you're doing this for homework (or something like that) where you're not allowed to use a decent library, I'd advise starting from `Boost` [ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Comment: i am not allowed to use them.thank you however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are lacking all error handling. When something goes wrong you have no idea why or how to fix it. **Always check for error conditions.**

In this particular case the problem seems to be with the `accept` call in the server: you are passing the socket length as the last parameter, when you should pass a pointer to the socket length. Also the socket length is being set to the size of an `int` initially. The code should be:

```
clilen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
clisocket = accept(sid,(struct sockaddr*)&cliinfo,(socklen_t*)&clilen);
```

A more subtle error is the fact that the server closes the socket with no guarantees of whether any of the data was actually sent. [Fixing this is more complicated though.](http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable)